# performance counter in c# - calculate average of sample

Tags: c#

hi
i am grabbing frames from ip camera and want to export via perf counters the time diff between frames. and present it as # timediff / sec.

i have created 2 counters one as

PerformanceCounterType.AverageCount64

and the seconds as

PerformanceCounterType.AverageBase

i am adding them ine after the other (the base come second)

for every frame i am calculating the diff and increase both counters e.g

```
pc.increaseby(40) 
pcbase.increaseby(1)
```

on second process i want to display the counter so when i am calculating

```
Single numerator = (Single)s1.RawValue - (Single)s0.RawValue;
Single denomenator = (Single)s1.BaseValue - (Single)s0.BaseValue;
Single counterValue = numerator / denomenator;
```

the basevalue is always 0 -> any ideas?

Comment: When you step through the code, take a look at each of the values (s1.RawValue, s0.RawValue, numerator, etc.). This will tell you what part of your code is not functioning properly.

Comment: Probably because the division is integer division rather than floating-point

Comment: @erikkallen: All of those values are Single (a.k.a. `float` in C#), so it's definitely floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, apparently I didn't read before I answered.